# Given Lt. Saru's innate fear, how would he ever make it to command?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In Star Trek Discovery there is a species of alien who evolved as prey to the other primary species of their particular world. On the Shen Zhou they have a Lt Commander (Lt. Saru) who is a member of this alien race and is a very fearful, almost cowardly, person who wants to run away from danger at any opportunity.

So the question is: Why and how would a person like this ever

1. enlist for a Command position and
2. even get through the academy far enough to reach any rank near enought to take the bridge in command?

Comment: If I've answered your question please click the green check mark below the vote scores to accept the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Doug Jones, the actor for Lt. Saru claims the survival instinct makes him a "badass"

From an interview that can be found on [IGN](http://www.ign.com/videos/2017/07/27/star-trek-discovery-doug-jones-explains-lt-saru-comic-con-2017) Doug says

> We're built in and born into a world where we look over our shoulders a lot, and what comes with that, that fear, is a protective and survival instinct. So that kind of makes me a badass, even though you think I'm a frail little species, when pushed into a corner, I can kick.

So really he feels he is not afraid and is fighting to take control of the Captain's chair.

Comment: Where in your quote (or anywhere else in canon) is it stated that he is *'fighting to take control of the Captain's chair'*? Granted, he covets and strives for a command position but your narrative seems to imply that he wants to usurp Lorca.

Comment: @Jeeped I took everything from the video interview, make what you will of it.