# Captain Lorcas first officer choice?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, captain-lorca

Why would Lorca want Saru as his XO? Lorca is a guy who wants to win at any cost. How does having a pacifist who freaks and wants to retreat every time his spidey-sense twitches serve that purpose?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your own question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170366/given-lt-sarus-innate-fear-how-would-he-ever-make-it-to-command)

Comment: It may seem like it but it's not.  2 different  captains with what appears to be completely  different  agendas and attitudes.

Comment: Yes but the premise of your question is that he's a coward, yet the answer to the other question explains that he's not simply a coward. He's simply a prey species, this gives him a heightened sense at getting out of sticky situations, which is a good skill for an XO.

Comment: But we have seen zero evidence  that portrays him as anything but a coward.

Comment: "Prey" does not necessarily mean "easy prey".  Flight is only *one* of Saru's possible responses to danger.

Comment: They have to survive long enough to win.

Comment: XO and First Officer and [not necessarily the same position](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kieran_MacDuff)

Answer (score 9):

The *Discovery* is, first and foremost, a science ship. Having an XO who is a former science officer is an obvious decision. Having an XO who is a former science officer *and* can instinctively sense the presence of danger even before it becomes apparent is an excellent decision.

Comment: *Was* it Lorca's decision? Putting different personalities together in a check-and-balance scenario is pretty standard. Perhaps it was Starfleet that made the decision.